# Task Scheduler IIS side with C#

Tags: c#, iis, scheduled-tasks, static-methods

I need to have tasks running in my web application. I have been reading and most of the answers are to use the task scheduler in Windows but what I need is to have it in the web application itself.

I finally got something that almost works but I am still having some troubles:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO;

namespace ServiceIIS
{
    public static class Servicios
    {
        public static bool serviceStarted = false;
        static Timer serviceLoad = new Timer();

        public static void serviceLoader()
        {
            if (!serviceStarted)
            {
                GC.KeepAlive(serviceStarted);
                GC.KeepAlive(serviceLoad);

                serviceStarted = true;

                double Intervalo = loadData();
                serviceLoad.Interval = Intervalo;
                serviceLoad.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(serviceLoad_Elapsed);
                serviceLoad.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        static void serviceLoad_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            serviceLoad.Stop();
            double Intervalo = loadData();
            serviceLoad.Interval = Intervalo;
            serviceLoad.Start();
        }

        static double loadData()
        {
            string dailyLoadTime = "00:00:00";
            string log = "";
            /*
                loadData Code
                log = resultMessage;
            */

            using (StreamWriter w = File.AppendText("c:\\log.txt"))
                {
                    writeLog(log, w);
                    w.Close();
                }

            return (Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddT") + dailyLoadTime).AddDays(1) - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds;
        }

        public static void writeLog(string resultMessage, TextWriter w)
        {
            w.Write("\r\nLog : ");
            w.WriteLine("{0} {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(),
                DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString());
            w.WriteLine("  :");
            w.WriteLine("  :{0}", resultMessage);
            w.WriteLine("-------------------------------");
            w.Flush();
        }
    }
}
```

serviceLoader() will be called if serviceStarted is false, then I tell the garbage collector to ignore serviceStarted and serviceLoad to be cleaned.
Calling loadData() for the first time to get the data and "generate" the interval for the timer to wait until loadData() is called again. Then I create the event handler and start the timer.

Using the writeLog() procedure I know when loadData() is called. Waiting for the time it should be called (00:00:00 hours), there is no calling to loadData() but until a different time... that could be because the way I am computing the interval is not entirely correct.

Then it is called again the same day and once the next day. Finally after the second day, there is no call at all for loadData() so I suppose it is because the garbage collector deleted it, calling serviceLoader() again, loadData() is called at the same time telling me that in effect serviceStarted has been cleaned and surely serveLoad has been cleaned too.

Do you have an idea on what I am doing wrong and how could I get this working? I could not believe that there is no way to do this using IIS.

Thank you in advance for your time reading this.

Elder

Comment: there is NO robust way to do this in IIS - the app pool / process gets reloaded on several occasions. there are config options but basically if IIS determines that it is necessary it will unload your appdomain/process and reload it!

Comment: And will this happen even if the application is being used? The application will be being used almost all day and loadData is supposed to be initialized at night. IIS will reload anyway getting serviceLoad cleaned?

Comment: YES - this will even when the application is being used...

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no entry point for the code you wrote. Typical aspnet entry is `Page_Load` but, in your purpouse, you must use `Application_Start` in `Global.asax` .

Anyway IIS web apps are not intended to host scheduled tasks, so I suggest to develop an .exe to be called by Task Scheduler ora a Windows Service instead.

Comment: The procedure serviceLoader is called at some point to do this test and then I leave it waiting just to know what is happening. I know that doing an .exe could be better but I needed it within IIS as I wrote before.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement this kind of logic in Windows service not IIS.